# Deleting a certain character from a text file in java

Tags: java, text, io, java.util.scanner

So I've recently received a large text file that I need to read unfortunately its formatted terribly as there are next line characters everywhere making it extremely difficult to read. So I've been trying to think of a way to sort through the file and delete each `nextLine` using a java program.

For example if we had this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus interdum      condimentum. Proin viverra   
justo vel imperdiet sagittis, purus sapien sagittis mi, et blandit purus ante non libero. Nulla ac   
augue ut odio eleifend interdum  
 ac id justo. Quisque rutrum euismod sem, vel euismod nunc convallis eu. Praesent odio velit,
 condimentum id scelerisque  
 iaculis, vulputate vitae lacus. Fusce adipiscing blandit libero eu venenatis.
 Vestibulum nec urna   
pulvinar arcu pretium   
pretium. Duis vitae augue dolor. Etiam consectetur feugiat
 diam sit amet gravida.
```

we would like it to turn out like this :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rhoncus interdum
condimentum. Proin viverra, justo vel imperdiet sagittis, purus sapien sagittis mi,       
blandit purus ante non libero. Nulla ac augue ut odio eleifend interdum ac id justo.
Quisque rutrum euismod sem, vel euismod nunc convallis eu. Praesent odio velit,
condimentum id scelerisque iaculis, vulputate vitae lacus. Fusce adipiscing blandit
libero eu venenatis. Vestibulum nec urna pulvinar arcu pretium pretium. Duis vitae
augue dolor
```

I'm not very experienced with reading/writing text file using Java. My current idea is reading in each char value checking if it is equal to the value of next line and proceeding to write that char to a separate text file if it is not. But i'm not really sure on how to implement this. I'm not sure how to check if a the next character is a next line.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why don't you assign each line to a string, and then apply your criteria to that string?

Comment: What is the EXCACT task you need to accomplish?

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer, but I don't think my answer fully does what you are looking for. Did you edit your post because you need more help?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to make a copy with an HTML extension and open it in a browser; html doesn't start new lines with the newline character.  I suppose, after that, you might want to go in and enter some angle-P-angle tags to break it where you DO want to, but it would save writing a program entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File("yourFilePath.txt");  // create File object to read from
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);       // create scanner to read
Printwriter writer = new PrintWriter("someOutputFile.txt"); // create file to write to

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){  // while there is a next line
    String line = scanner.nextLine();  // line = that next line

    // do something with that line
    String newLine = "";

    // replace a character
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
        if (line.charAt(i) != '*') {  // or anything other character you chose
            newLine += line.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    // print to another file.
    writer.println(newLine);
}
```

You could also just write back to the same file, but that would require using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: It is always better to use a stringbuffer or a stringbuilder (immutable datatypes) for such operations where there is so much string append operations involved, rather than concatenating with a string (mutable) reference because new string objects get created everytime which is unnecessary.

Comment: @Patrick Yes you are correct! **Disclaimer:** I posted this in my very early days of programming.

Comment: LOL ! just a chance to look back on the code you wrote and compare yourself with your past coding level :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Scanner to do this.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));
String new_file_string = "";
while (in.hasNextLine())
    new_file_string += in.nextLine();
// write new_file_string to file.
```

Comment: I wasn't aware Scanner had that method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a BufferedReader, and make use of the `readLine()` method to read the file a line at a time.

- When you read an empty line, the method will return a (non-null) empty string.
- When you get to the end of file, the method will return a null.
- Otherwise, the method will return the line ... with the line terminator removed.  (So when you output the line, don't forget to add a line terminator!)

This should be enough for you to write the program yourself.  (And that would be a GOOD THING!)

Comment: but won't that only work for completely empty lines?

Comment: Well yes.  If you want to remove lines that are not "completely empty", you will need to test for them.  But since you don't say what the criteria for removal are, I can't tell you how to do that test.

Comment: On the other hand, If you are really wanting to remove ONLY the newlines, then modify the 3rd bullet to NOT add the line terminators back! However, I'd not have considered removing the newlines a good way to improve readability.