# Remove Character from text file

Tags: java

Hope you can get me started.

I have a ldif file which contains a ASCII character '\' which I want to remove from all occurrence within the file. So to do this I need to read the file and any line that for example has

```
dn: cn=test\_user1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

remove the slash.

Can you please help.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is customary that a question contain evidence of your attempts.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885354/deleting-a-certain-character-from-a-text-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( YOUR_FILE_HERE ));
String line;
while( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.isEmpty) continue;
    line = line.replace('\\', '');
    ... blah-blah-blah ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I am now making progress